# Firebase Email Validation Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, credentials, email-validation

I have this piece of code to sign up:

```
      Future<String> signUp({String email, String password}) async {
    try{
      await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

      return "Signed up";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
      print("no se puede crear");
      return e.message;
    }
  }
```

I need to implement the validation mail from firebase, this has been asked a lot and I came up with this when researching, some code is deprecated and its hard for me to find guidance:

```
    Future<String> signUp({String email, String password}) async {
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    try {
      await user.sendEmailVerification();
      return user.uid;
    } catch (e) {
      print("An error occured while trying to send email        verification");
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
  }
```

But cant figure how to implement it because it throws:

> A value of type 'UserCredential' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'FirebaseUser'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/createUserWithEmailAndPassword.html) doesn't return a FirebaseUser object.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, it yields a [UserCrediental](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential-class.html) object.  That's what the error message is trying to tell you - you can't assign a UserCredential to a FirebaseUser typed variable.

If you wan to get a FirebaseUser object out of a UserCredential, you can simply use its [user](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential/user.html) property.

```
UserCredential credential = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
FirebaseUser user = credential.user;
```